# How to use abstract class if i need to initialize the child ones?

Tags: java, object, interface, polymorphism, abstract

I have pojo class - "Person" and classes extends this: "Employee" and "Customer". I want to make a method for custom testing. But i don't know in advance which one(Employee or Customer) will be needed. I would like to write this method for 2 entities. How to write something in 'p' variable initialise. Some classes to extend Person. My code isn't working. Thanks in advance. I would like to fill the common fields for both entities. Can i realize this without using an interface?

```
public static Person fillRandomRecord(){
    Person p = <? extends Person>;
    p.setName(getRandomName());
    p.setSurname(getRandomSurname());
    p.setPatronymic(getRandomPatronymic());
    p.setDateOfBirth(getRandomDate());
    p.setPhone(getRandomPhone());
    p.setEmail(getRandomEmail());
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make the method accept Person as a parameter `public static Person fillRandomRecord(Person p){...}` and then just give it either `fillRandomRecord(new Customer())` or `fillRandomRecord(new Employee())` when you're calling it.

Comment: Thanks. It was too simple)